# Access iphone photos and videos from cygwin or powershell

Tags: iphone, cygwin, mtp

I would like to write a cygwin application that interacts with an iPhone that is connected to a windows 10 computer via the usb port.

The iphone shows up in windows as a device, not as a drive.

I have tried to compile and run the libmtp cygwin library but none of the sample applications seem to be able to access a connected iphone.

How can an application access a connected iPhone and read the photos and videos stored on it?